# Dynamically retrieve the Name of a ScriptProperty in the Get and Set block

Tags: class, powershell, powershell-5.0

### Goal

I'm looking to utilize the new `Class` feature of PowerShell 5 to create a class that i can use within my project to view records of a database and create methods to link and unlink foreign keys together.

The below class is working with 2 properties but i need to add more and don't want to copy/paste, this is how it's currently working:

```
# Create a new instance of my Computer class
$computer = [Computer]::new([int]71)

# Change the status of the Server in the DataRow
$computer.Status = "Active"

# Update the Row in the Database
$computer.SaveChanges()

# Link this Server in the Database to a record in the Locations table
$computer.LinkLocation([int]16)
```

I've got the `Class` part and even a few `Methods` implemented but i'm wondering if i can reduce the amount of code needed in the class by somehow referencing the `Name` property of a `ScriptProperty`.

### Class

```
class Computer
{
    hidden [System.Data.DataRow]$_dataRow
    hidden [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter]$_dataAdapter

    hidden GetComputerDetails([int]$serverId)
    {
        $connectionString = "Server=HomeTestServer\DB01;Database=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

        $sqlQuery = "SELECT ComputerName, Status FROM tbComputers WHERE Id = $serverId"

        $sqlConnection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ArgumentList $connectionString

        $sqlCommand = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand -ArgumentList $SqlQuery, $sqlConnection

        $sqlConnection.Open()

        $sqlAdapter = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter -ArgumentList $sqlCommand

        $sqlData = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet

        $sqlBuilder = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder -ArgumentList $sqlAdapter

        $sqlAdapter.Fill($sqlData, "Computer")

        $this._dataRow = $sqlData.Tables[0].Rows[0]
        $this._dataAdapter = $sqlAdapter
    }

    hidden [object] GetValue([string]$propertyName)
    {
        return $this._dataRow.$propertyName
    }

    hidden SetValue([string]$propertyName, $value)
    {
        $this._dataRow.$propertyName = $value
    }

    SaveChanges()
    {
        $this._dataAdapter.Update($this._dataRow)
    }

    LinkLocation([int]$locationId)
    {
        $serverId = $this._dataRow.Id

        [void](Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "HomeTestServer\DB01" -Database TestDB -Query "UPDATE tbComputers SET LocationId = $locationId WHERE Id = $serverId" )
    }

    Computer([int]$serverId)
    {
        $this.GetComputerDetails([int]$serverId)

        $this | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name ComputerName -Force -Value `
        {
            # Is there a way to get the ScriptProperty's Name?
            $this.GetValue("ComputerName")
        } `
        {
            param
            (
                $value
            )
            # Is there a way to get the ScriptProperty's Name?
            $this.SetValue("ComputerName", $value) 
        }

        $this | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name Status -Force -Value `
        {
            # Is there a way to get the ScriptProperty's Name?
            $this.GetValue("Status")
        } `
        {
            param
            (
                $value
            )
            # Is there a way to get the ScriptProperty's Name?
            $this.SetValue("Status", $value) 
        }
    }
}
```

### Explanation

This class essentially wraps the `DataRow` and `DataAdapter` for easy record viewing and updating as the `ScriptProperty`'s modify the values directly on the `DataRow` and the `Savechanges` method updates the `DataRow` using the `DataAdapter`

### Problem

For each property that i want to wrap in my `Class`, i need to make a `ScriptProperty` with a `Getter` and a `Setter`, the above `Class` has 2 properties and doesn't look to bad but what if my SQL Table had 40 properties? I really do not want to copy and paste the `$this | Add-Member...` line 40 times.

Ideally i'm looking for a way to loop through and create each `ScriptProperty` dynamically

### Attempts

```
foreach($propertyName in $this._dataRow.Table.Columns)
{
    # Looping through doesn't work, my working theory is the Get/Set block don't expand the variable when the Member is being added, only when it's being called
    $this | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name $propertyName -Force -Value `
    {
        # This is the Get block
        $this.GetValue($propertyName)
    } `
    {
        param
        (
            $value
        )
        # This is the Set block
        $this.SetValue($propertyName, $value)
    }
}
```

### Edit

Highly simplified example:

```
class Computer
{
    hidden [int]$number3 = 4
    hidden [int]$number2 = 13

    hidden ExtractFields([string]$propertyName)
    {

        $this | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name $propertyName -Force -Value `
        {
            $this.GetValue($propertyName)
        } `
        {
            param
            (
                $value
            )
            $this.SetValue($propertyName,$value)
        }
    }

    hidden [object] GetValue($propertyName)
    {
        return $this.$propertyName
    }

    hidden SetValue($propertyName, $value)
    {
        $this.$propertyName = $value
    }

    Computer()
    {
        foreach($property in @('number2', 'number3'))
        {
            $this.ExtractFields($property)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Image Example]

Error recieved when trying to set a dynamic property (e.g `$computer.number2 = 17)

```
Exception setting "number2": "The property '' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
At line:1 char:1
+ $computer.number2 = 17
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptSetValueRuntimeException
```

### Question

Is there a way i can dynamically create `ScriptProperty`'s based on specified property name?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with dynamic generation of scriptblocks for the setters and getters. Suppose class `Bar` is defined with two methods that implement a general way to access your fields:

```
class Bar
{
    [object] GetFieldValue ( [string] $FieldName )
    {
        # replace this with code that looks up your value by field name
        Write-Host "Invoked GetFieldValue($FieldName)"
        return "value of $FieldName"
    }
    SetFieldValue ( [string] $FieldName, [object] $Value )
    {
        # replace this with code that sets your field value
        Write-Host "Invoked SetFieldValue($FieldName,$Value)"
    }
}
```

A function can then be implemented that decorates a `Bar` object with dynamically-generated properties that have getters and setters that invoke those methods:

```
function New-Bar
{
    param( [string[]]$FieldNames )

    # create the new object
    $outputObject = [Bar]::new()

    # add a property for each field
    foreach ( $fieldName in $FieldNames )
    {
        $getter = [scriptblock]::Create(
            "`$this.GetFieldValue('$fieldName')"
        )
        $setter = [scriptblock]::Create(
            "`param(`$p) `$this.SetFieldValue('$fieldName',`$p)"
        )
        $outputObject | 
            Add-Member ScriptProperty $fieldName $getter $setter -Force
    }

    # return the object
    $outputObject
}
```

Fields can then be accessed like this:

```
$b = New-Bar 'field1','field2'
$b.field1 = 'my value for field 1'
$b.field1
```

Which outputs:

```
Invoked GetFieldValue(field1)
value of field1
Invoked SetFieldValue(field1,my value for field 1)
```